# Generating DAG from another DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I want to crate DAG from another DAG dynamically, e.g. when operator will trigger this parent DAG, it should generate new dag.

The following codes runs without errors but DAG is not created.

I can't see the reason.

```
def generate_dag():

    def do_something():
        print('something')

    default_args = {            
        'schedule_interval': '@hourly',
        'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        'is_paused_upon_creation': True
    }

    dag = DAG("generated_dag",
              default_args=default_args,
              catchup=False
              )
    with dag:
        do_something = PythonOperator(
            task_id="do_something",
            python_callable=do_something,
            dag=dag
        )
        do_something

    return dag



default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',       
    'max_active_runs': 1,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    'createme',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2019,4,29),
    catchup=False,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
)

def create_dag():
    dag = generate_dag()
   
    globals()['generated_dag'] = dag

create = PythonOperator(
    task_id="create",
    python_callable=create_dag,    
    dag=dag
)    
create
```

I don't want to generate DAG python **files** in the dags folder.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `createme` DAG, just run `create_dag`. Astronomer has a great article with examples https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/

```py
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow import DAG


def generate_dag():

    def do_something():
        print('something')

    default_args = {            
        'schedule_interval': '@hourly',
        'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        'is_paused_upon_creation': True
    }

    dag = DAG("generated_dag",
              default_args=default_args,
              catchup=False
              )
    with dag:
        do_something = PythonOperator(
            task_id="do_something",
            python_callable=do_something,
            dag=dag
        )
        do_something

    return dag

def create_dag():
    dag = generate_dag()
   
    globals()['generated_dag'] = dag

create_dag()
```